# Rails Validation On Attribute Update Based on Another Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I have three related models, an Account which has one program and has one profile. When an account is created, profile.email can be nil so long as `program.upgraded == 'f'`. But how can I, and where should I, validate that profile.email has been set, i.e. is not nil, before setting `program.upgraded` to 't'.

So I've tried creating a custom validation, but I may not be implementing this properly. I have a service that calls

```
program.update!(
      upgraded: 't',
    )
```

inside a transaction block that rescues on an exception. Here's my validation:

```
class Account::Program < ApplicationRecord
  validate :upgraded, :upgraded_email_present
  ...
  private
  def upgraded_email_present
    return unless ppc_p == 't' && account.profile.auto_email.blank?
    errors[:upgraded] << "profile auto_email must be set"
  end
  ...
end
```

The update! statement appears to be failing, and it triggers the rescue in that the transaction block is in with the correct error. However, when I check the model instance, it's still been upgraded! Totally confused on what's wrong here.

EDIT

Finally realized what's going on. I was testing the validation in the context of my specs and had to do a reload on the instance. This solution works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom validator ([Rails docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations)) for more complex validations like what you're after. An `ActiveModel::EachValidator` implements `.validate_each`, which takes the arguments:

1. the record being validated
2. the attribute being validated
3. the current value of that attribute

```rb
class UpgradeEmailPresentValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    # All good if :upgraded is false or if the profile email is present
    return unless value? && record.account.profile.email.blank?

    record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "profile email must be set")
  end
end
 
class Program < ApplicationRecord
  validates :upgraded, presence: true, upgrade_email_present: true
end
```

You didn't say if `Program` is associated with a `Profile` via `has_one :through`, but if it does you can shorten `record.account.profile` to just `record.profile`.

**EDIT**

I neglected to mention in my original that you can also use a custom validation method on the model as well.

```rb
class Program < ApplicationRecord
  validate :upgraded, :upgrade_email_present

  def upgrade_email_present
   return unless upgraded? && account.profile.email.blank?

   errors[:upgraded] << "profile email must be set"
  end
end
```

Comment: Does this have to be done by creating a new class? Can I define a method to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, you can also use a custom validation method (answer edited with details). I originally started my answer thinking to use a common validator for both ``Program`` and ensuring you can't set email to ``nil`` if ``profile.upgraded`` is set -- which is something an extracted validator class is useful for --  but ended up trimming that part out to keep it simple.